# How can I tell if this is a significant result?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, stochastic-processes, random-generation

I have a script which randomly generates test cases for a certain data type and throws these at an algorithm which in turn returns a positive or negative result.

From this I simple calculate positive %.

So I get something like

Type1 ~ 80%;
Type2 ~ 50%

The problem is I am not sure what is the standard deviation here or how confident I am with my results. Obviously n = number of test cases is important but knowing n to be say 1000, can I have a statistical test to see if if is reasonable to say that Type1 and Type2 are performing differently against the algorithm in question.

I am also curious if n = 1000 makes more sense than say n = 50 ran 20 times and taking the mean result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the absolute numbers you can construct a contingency table and use chi-square test of independence to compare 80% in Type A with 50% in Type B.